# Why my physical iPhone not showing in xcode for testing an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, vmware

I am using iphone 6 and i have connected my phone to xcode with cable. But it is not shoing in "Device & Simulator". I have installed the OS Mojave with VMware. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe simple. The phone has to be unlocked before it appears in Xcode. It might say 'Unlock iPhone to use accessories'.

Comment: How I will do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must transfer your usb device in VmWare, to make avaible to your virtual machine so mojave detect the usb device and xcode recognize your iphone, VMWare has a menu where show the options and there is a device list so you can transfert to your virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to authorize the app on your device (iPhone):

Settings > General > Device Management, then select the appropriate profile and trust it